# What are the clicking sounds when static electricity occurs?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, statics

Sometimes, when there's static electricity, soft *clicking sounds* can be heard. This may happen when two fabrics are rubbed or when you get a static shock. What exactly causes this sounds?

Comment: Miniature lightning bolts.

Comment: @JonCuster Awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to static discharge. When the electric field between two points in a medium exceeds the dielectric strength of the medium, then dielectric breakdown happens, and the medium becomes sort of a conductor, with charges getting exchanged between the two points. However, since the medium becomes conducting, due to the huge values of the electric field strength, the charges being exchanged acquire huge velocities over shorter distance than the mean free path in such a medium and thus their collisions with neighboring atoms excite them to higher energy states as well as to sudden high velocities, leading to rapid thermal expansion and light emission. That is the reason for the sound and the light of such discharges. In short, as @JonCuster calls it, miniature lightning bolts.